# bibliography does not work; bibliography does not appear afterpdflatex and bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am writing my thesis, I used to use latex for paper and it works all fine. but for the long thesis, I got problem with my bibliography.

I learned that I should do this via

```
pdflatex MainFile
bibtex MainFile
pdflatex MainFile
pdflatex MainFile
```

I have no problem or warning until the second step. After the second step I have this in MainFile.bbl

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Wielen}
S.~T. Abedon, P.~Hyman, and C.~Thomas.
\newblock Experimental examination of bacteriophage latent-period evolution as
  a response to bacterial availability.
\newblock {\em Applied and Environmental Microbiology}, 69:7499--7506, 2003.

\end{thebibliography}
```

and I have this in MainFile.blg

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: Yan_Thesis.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Titlepage/Titlepage.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Contents/Introduction.aux
The style file: unsrt.bst
Database file #1: Contents/thesis_reference.bib
```

it all seems ok. But the third step gives me error

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Wielen' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.

[1] [2]) [3] [4] (D:\PHD_study\Yans_work\Thesis\Yan\Yan_Thesis.bbl

! Package graphics Error: Division by 0.

See the graphics package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{1}

?
```

Process has been terminated ...

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Following is my MainFile.tex

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside,openright,english,fleqn,showtrims]{memoir/memoir}
\input{Definitions/Margindefinitions.tex}
\input{Definitions/Packageinputs.tex}
\input{Definitions/Pagedefinition.tex}
\input{Definitions/Colordefinition.tex}
\input{Definitions/Headerdefinition.tex}
\input{Definitions/Floatdefinitions.tex}
%\makeindex
\input{Definitions/Hyphens}

\begin{document}
     \frontmatter
     \setcounter{page}{1001}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \include{Titlepage/Titlepage}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagestyle{ruled}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
       \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}%
        \maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

        \pagestyle{summarystyle}

        \cleardoublepage

        \cleardoublepage
        \pagestyle{ruled}
        \tableofcontents*%
        \cleardoublepage


    \mainmatter%
        \pagestyle{ruled} %dit bepaalt de headerstyle
      \include{Contents/Introduction}




    \appendix
        \pagestyle{poststyle}


    \backmatter%
        \pagestyle{ruled}
     \bibliographystyle{unsrt}%
       \pagestyle{bibstyle}
        \hyphenpenalty=0
        \bibliography{Contents/thesis_reference}
        \hyphenpenalty=15000
        \cleardoublepage

        \cleardoublepage
        \pagestyle{listofpubs}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a style that's doing some scaling or rotating of something while setting up the bibliography , you'll get div by zero if you try for example to scale a 0pt high box to a non zero value as it would need an infinite scale factor

Comment: Dear  David, thank you for  your comment. I got this answer via googling. But i am not sure where it can be wrong...I attaches also my main tex file. I got this thesis template from someone else who i can not reach at this moment...while the style of bibliography is set by         \pagestyle{ruled}
     \bibliographystyle{unsrt}%
       \pagestyle{bibstyle}, which i am not clear how they can be wrong.